# Issues reading a paper about batteries

Tags: dimensional-analysis, batteries

I am looking for answers regarding a paper I am reading right now. I either found stupidly high values or strange SI unit. This paper is about battery charging, and the battery model used brings me some questions.

First, I have the following formula:

$$\beta_i(k)=\frac{C_iV_i(k)^2}{2\eta_i\Delta t}$$ where $C_i$ is the capacitance in Farads, $\eta_i$ the charging efficiency (neutral), $V_i(k)$ the voltage in Volts and $\Delta t$ in seconds.

This formula is used with the maximum power a battery can handle (in kW) in order to calculate one coefficient, $K_1(k)$, used to approximate a non-linear function with a linear one. My problem is that when I compute $K_1(k)$, I got stupidly high values, making the approximated function way to different of the original one (where the paper shows that they are very close). I have then computed the S.I. of $\beta_i(k)$ and I obtained this:

$$\beta_i(k) = \frac{s^4.A^2.m^{-2}.kg^{-1}.(kg.m^2.s^{-3}.A^{-1})^2}{s}$$
which is equal to $s^{-1}.m^{-2}.kg$, which is the unit of the angular momentum ... Does it have sense for a battery ? Didn't I make any mistakes ? I am not quite familiar with dimensional analysis.

Thank you very much.

edit: The paper can be found here: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6730946/

My problem is in page 4, section III - B, where you will find approximation coefficient $K_1(k)$. You can find $\beta_i(k)$ in page 3, section II - D.

If you cannot access to the paper, the formula of $K_1(k)$ is the following (a bit long):

$$9P_{i,max}^{-1}\sqrt{P_{i,max}^2 + \beta P_{i,max}} \\ - 8 P_{i,max}^{-3/2}(\beta + P_{i,max})^{3/2} \\ + 8 \beta^{3/2}P_{i,max}^{-3/2} - 2.5\beta^2P_{i,max}^{-2} \\* \ln(\beta /2 + P_{i,max} + \sqrt{P_{i,max}(\beta + P_{i,max}}) \\ +4.5\beta P_{i,max}^{-2}\sqrt{P_{i,max}^2+\beta P_{i,max}} \\ +2.5\beta^2 P_{i,max}^{-2}\ln(\beta/2)$$

Using a capacitance of 7200F (Battery of 20 A.h capacity), a Voltage $V_i(k)$ of 240V, a $\Delta t$ of 600s and $\eta$ = 1, I find $\beta = 345600~W$, which is pretty high regarding the results they obtained in the paper.  (I came up to W and not N.m.s just by switching the capacitance to $\frac{A.s}{V}$).

edit: Ok so if, as in the paper example, I would like to have $\beta_k(i) = 1000$, I need to have, for $\Delta t = 600s$ and $\eta = 1$ either $C_i = 20.833F$, which sounds pretty strange, or $V_i(k) = 12.9V$, which seems to be OK. My problem is that in the paper, it is not wrote if $V_i(k)$ is the difference between the Voltage at the battery max. State of Charge (SOC) and the voltage at the battery minimum SOC. I am pretty sure it is not, as it entails that $V_i(k)$ will be a constant, and so not in function of k. Except if, of course, this value is computed for each k based on the current SOC and not the minimum SOC ...

Does it seem OK to take the voltage difference instead of the nominal voltage at a given step k ? The paper is really not clear about this.

Comment: $CV^2/2$ is a measure of energy, so $CV^2/2\Delta t$ is a measure of power. Check you are using consistent units - for example the SI unit for capacitance is the Farad, but real capacitor values are often specified in  microFarads.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. In the paper I am reading, they are assuming that the capacitance is computed from the nominal capacity in Coulombs, divided by Voltage, which produces a value in Farads, not in microFarads. However, there is no indication if they are using microFarads or not, and the SI units used are not well defined, I am doing my calculation based on some example values they provide ... I am going to try considering microFarads instead, checking if the value are decreasing to smthg consistent.

Comment: Did not find anything more interesting than what I have put. It is very strange, I am getting pretty wrong result and I really don't have any idea why.

Comment: If you give a reference to the complete paper, somebody might be able to help, but without that, you are just asking "My calculation doesn't make sense, what did I do wrong?" - and we aren't mind-readers! The formula in your OP doesn't even define what $K_1(k)$ is.

Comment: I will add an edit, sorry about that.

Comment: *"where $w_i(k)$ is a priority (number, neutral dimension)"* I am, of course, always pleased to see terms defined, but ... $w_i$ does not appear in the proceeding line.

Comment: Oh you are right I am sorry. I will delete it, I wanted to add another formula with $w_i(k)$ but I finally deleted it.